# For what complex $z$ the series converges

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

Can someone help me with this assignment?

> Find for what $z \in \mathbb{C}$ the series converges
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}z^n$.

I've just calculated (by using Cauchy-Hadamard theorem) that for all $z$ such that $|z|<\frac{1}{4}$ this series converges and for all $z$ such that $|z|>\frac{1}{4}$ it doesn't. I don't know how to check $|z|=\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Are you sure you need to check the convergence on the boundary of the region of convergence?

Comment: Hint: can you find $\lim \frac{(2n)!}{n!^24^n}$?

Comment: [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) (or Stirling) should help too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$ has the Taylor expansion $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} z^n$ in the vicinity of $z = 0$.
For $z \ne \frac14$ on the circle $|z| = \frac14$, the function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4z}}$ is regular there and there is no apriori reason why the sequence must diverge. In fact, if one use the [Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) of $n!$ and look at the series at $z = \frac14 e^{i\theta}$, we have

$$\binom{2n}{n} z^n \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} e^{in\theta} ( 1 + O(\frac{1}{n} ))\quad
\text{for large }n.$$
Since the correction term has the order $O(n^{-\frac32})$, its "contribution" in the original series always converges. This means the two series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n} z^n\quad\text{ and }\quad
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}} e^{in\theta}$$

converges and diverges at the same time. By [Dirichlet test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), the second series does converge when $\theta \ne 0$. From this, we can conclude the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{2n}{n} z^n$ converges for all $z \ne \frac14$ on the circle $|z| = \frac14$.